# Reporting Tools like Elastic Search with data-level Authorization

Tags: elasticsearch

Looking for a reporting tool / feature / open source which can support data-level authorization. I think Elastic Search does not provide data level authorization rather it is based only on cluster / indices level.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Shield plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks Val for your response. Yes, I had a look on Shield. But Shield provides authorization only over CLUSTER and INDICES level. Not on data-level authorization.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure what "level" exactly you meant by "data-level". You should maybe beef up your very concise question to include some more info. Do you want to restrain access at the document level (user X can see doc, user X cannot), or further down at the field level (both users X and Y can see the doc, but only X can see field A)?

Comment: 2nd case: both users X and Y can see the doc, but only X can see field A

Comment: Hi Val, if you know the answer, could you please update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of [Shield 2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/shield-and-watcher-2-0-0-beta2-released) (still in beta though) you can now set up [field- and document-level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/setting-up-field-and-document-level-security.html)

```
roleX:
  indices:
    '*':
      privileges: read
      fields:
        - fieldA             <-- only users with roleX can see fieldA
        - fieldB

roleY:
  indices:
    '*':
      privileges: read
      fields:
        - fieldB
```

Comment: To whoever needs to [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), it's a good practice to comment the reason why you're downvoting and think this is not a valid answer, so that everyone can benefit from your constructive criticism.